# python StatsModels use training parameters for test data summary

Tags: regression, time-series, python, statsmodels, pandas

I ran a linear regression on a month of hourly Nox concentration using `StatsModels` ols function. 
 how can I get summary OLS Regression Results on the test data? I was able to predict for new data but I want to get parameters like `AIC` and `R-squared` :

```
    %matplotlib inline
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # read in data    
    path =r'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTDUZROQwAMckLFWFk6ltL5eBxamCcaqzeKSJjrhhKIB0beXNH_MKfNK8LVlIS71pb4FdgC98xzVdCg/pub?output=csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(path, skipinitialspace=True)
    df = df[1:]

    # take care of datetimeindex
    Date = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,-1], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    Date.name = 'Date'
    Time =  pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,-2], format='%H:%M:%S')
    hour = Time.dt.hour
    hour.name = "hour"
    Weekday = Date.dt.weekday_name
    Weekday.name = 'weekday'
    month = Date.dt.strftime('%b')
    month.name = 'month'
    day = Date.dt.strftime('%a')
    day.name = 'day'
    weekend = Weekday=='Saturday'
    weekend.name = 'weekend'

    # clean data
    tim = Date.dt.date.astype(str) + " " +  Time.dt.time.astype(str)
    date_time = pd.to_datetime(tim)
    date_time.name = 'date_time'
    clean_df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    clean_df = pd.concat([clean_df.iloc[:,:-2], Weekday, hour, month, weekend], axis =1)
    clean_df.index = date_time
    print((clean_df.isnull().sum()/len(clean_df)) *100)
    df_nona = clean_df[['No2','Nox', 'WS', 'WD', 'weekday', 'hour', 'month', 'weekend']]
    df_nona = df_nona.dropna()

    # wind direction to Dummy variables
    directions = np.array('N NNE NE ENE E ESE SE SSE S SSW SW WSW W WNW NW NNW N'.split())
    bins = np.arange(11.25, 360, 22.5)
    binned_wind_direction = directions[np.digitize(df_nona['WD'], bins)]
    df_nona["binned_wd"] =  binned_wind_direction
    WD = pd.get_dummies(df_nona['binned_wd'])

    lin_model = pd.concat([df_nona,WD], axis=1 )
    lin_model =lin_model.dropna()
    lin_model.hour = lin_model.hour.astype('str')
    train = lin_model['2016-01-01':'2016-03-01']
    test =lin_model['2016-03-02':'2016-03-05']

    # run linear regression
    train_mode =ols("""Nox ~ weekend
                                        + hour
                                        + E
                                        + ENE
                                        + ESE
                                        + N
                                        + NE
                                        + NNE
                                        + NNW
                                        + NW
                                        + S
                                        + SE
                                        + SSE
                                        + SSW
                                        + SW
                                        + W
                                        + WNW
                                        + WSW
                                        + WS""", data=train).fit()
 print(train_mode_summary)
```

[image]

```
 test_dat = train_mode.predict(test)
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,4))
 test_dat['2016-03-02':'2016-03-05'].plot(ax=ax, style='r')
 df_nona['2016-03-02':'2016-03-05'].Nox.plot( ax=ax, style='k.', alpha=0.4)
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you want aic on test data, where the penalty loses its meaning?

Comment: i would like to know how good my model is not only the AIC but all the summary

Comment: Many of those statistics only make sense on training data. Aic, bic, f statistic, r squared, adj r squared are meant to be used on training data. Asking for their test values makes no sense.

Comment: why does  r squared  make sense only on the training data?

Comment: Thats the only debatable one, but the reaon is explained in this paper: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/157/Papers/shmueli.pdf  Even if you still want it, r squared is simple to program yourself.